# YUM package "NPM" makes trouble

Tags: fedora, yum, npm

When I try to install npm like this

```
sudo yum install npm
```

I get this error:

```
Fehler:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
        cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
        pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

      1. You have an upgrade for v8 which is missing some
         dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
         solve this by installing an older version of v8 of the
         different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
         yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
         requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
         --exclude v8.otherarch ... this should give you an error
         message showing the root cause of the problem.

      2. You have multiple architectures of v8 installed, but
         yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
         If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
         can remove the one with the missing update and everything
         will work.

      3. You have duplicate versions of v8 installed already.
         You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

    ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
    this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
    do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
    much more problems).

    Geschützte Multilib-Versionen: 1:v8-3.17.6.14-2.fc19.x86_64 != 1:v8-3.14.5.10-2.fc19.i686
```

I'm running Fedora 19 x86_64.

There is this log:
https://pastee.org/wetpc

Comment: Did you read the error message? Did you read the yum output?

Comment: It's in German, pls reset LANG to C and repost

Comment: english: https://pastee.org/j3mrj and yes, I read the error, but I'm new to this, so it would be kind if you'd explain what's the matter and tell me how to fix it...

Comment: What version of Fedora?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have installed a earlier version of `v8` (your pastebin says: "---> Package v8.x86_64 1:3.14.5.10-2.fc19 will be updated") that can't be properly updated via yum (because of some other dependencies).

You can check that with: `yum list installed | grep v8`

Then uninstall v8: `yum remove v8*` (This will probably result in a orgy of removing all packages that depend on it. If so, just reinstall them later after the npm install.)

After that you should be able to install npm

```
yum install npm
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
yum list installed v8
```

...and to fix the problem, this will likely work:

```
yum distro-sync v8
```